# Cyanogenmod remains in a bootloader loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, reboot, htc-wildfire, boot-loop

Hello I have a Wildfire and I installed Cyanogenmod 7.2.0 following this guide: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/HTC_Wildfire:_Full_Update_Guide

After I did this the keyboard stopped working so I used Revolutionary to install this keyboard with the zip file: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964663

And now it keeps rebooting with the cyanogen animation. And after that I get the Welcome to HTC Wildfire screen, but if I press anything or do nothing it reboots again.

How can I at least reboot normally, or preferably reinstall the whole mobile phone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait.... CM 7.2, that linky to the xda states explicitly as a pre-requisite: ***Must be running 4.0+***.... just saying...

Comment: A while ago, I brought my Wildfire up to CM 9.1. This included first flashing a radio image (`buzz.radio-3.35.20.10-signed.zip`) via CWM, followed by `CM 9.1 - buzz.zip` and the fitting GApps. I cannot remember the sources, but maybe googling the filenames will help you out. The radio could be the clue here.